# execvp , redirecion of output of ls

Tags: shell, operating-system, execvp

I am trying to build a shell in C language for OS project. The problem is coming when I am doing redirection part. `ls` is working fine, but when I do `ls > somefile`. It gives me an error " ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory ". Here is that part of my code

```
while(in){
    argv[c]=strdup(in); \\in is output of strtok applied on input string
    in=strtok(NULL,"\n , ");
    c++;
}
argv[c]=NULL;

int rc=fork();
if(rc==0){
    int flag = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int i;
    for(i= 0; i <c;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(argv[i],">") == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            index = i+1;
        }
        if(flag == 1)
        {
            fclose(stdout);
            fopen(argv[index],"w+");
        }
        execvp(argv[0],argv);
     }
else if(rc>0){
    (void) wait(NULL);}
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error from `ls` is telling you that you passed `>` to `ls` as an argument.

So let us look at your `execvp` call:

```
execvp(argv[0],argv);
```

So you are using the entirety of `argv` as the arguments to the spawned `ls`.

Where, in the processing above that call, are you removing the redirection arguments that you've already handled from `argv` so that `ls` doesn't see them?

Side note: Are you assuming that that `fopen` will assign your newly opened file the fd previously used by `stdout`? That seems like an unwise assumption to me (even if it normally works).

Oh, and your indentation could use some work.

Comment: I guess i saw the problem. I wasn't removing redirection argument. And yes i am assuming fopen will assign descripter 1 to the new file. I don't know how to do it by any other way. @Eten Reisner

Comment: @AnmolYousaf See [`man fopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) there's another function in there that will be useful to you. Also possibly [`man dup`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dup).